# How Can I Put at Headings the Title of my book?

Tags: sectioning

I want put on odd pages the chapter follow by the number page. And, at the even pages the number page followed by the title. The question is: HOW?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The answer to your question depends heavily on the document class you're using. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Then we can work from that to determine the correct way to set up the headings for your document.

Comment: Like \pagestyle{headings}?

Comment: KOMA classes or at least `scrlayer-scrpage2` package or `fancyhdr` do wonders ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the standard `book` class, you can use  the `titleps` package, from the `titlesec` bundle.  Just add this code to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagetyle{mystyle]{%
\titlerule% if you want a header rule
\sethead[\thepage\quad\chaptertitle][][]{}{}{\chapterritle\quad\thepage}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}%
\pagestyle{mypage}
```

If you prefer to have the chapter title centred in  header, you'll write:

```
\sethead[\thepage][\chaptertitle][]{}{\chaptertitle}{\thepage}
```

See the documentation for further details on examples and possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

With a KOMA-Script class like `scrbook` you can simply use following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\pagemark\quad\expandafter\MakeMarkcase\csname @title\endcsname}
\rohead{\headmark\quad\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\title{Title of the Document}
\author{Author of the Document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that the pages with the chapter headings do not show a running head by default.

If you are using a standard class, `\@title` will be removed after `\maketitle`. So using a new command could be a simple solution:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mwe}
\newcommand*{\Title}{Title of the Document}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\pagemark\quad\MakeMarkcase{\Title}}
\rohead{\headmark\quad\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\title{\Title}
\author{Author of the Document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```